# Is it possible to upload an entire folder to Google Drive using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am currently exploring Google Drive APIs and am able to upload an individual file using Postman successfully.

I tried to create/upload a folder using Google Drive API but failed. In fact, I don't see any specific API to deal with a folder. I was giving it a try with create files API.

Reference - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) you will notice at the top it states

> Creates a file.

This is singular each request creates a single file. If you want to upload a directory you will need to first create the directory then upload each file one at a time.

You could try batching but I don't think you can batch the file upload itself you could probably batch the metadata creation [performance#details](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#details)

Comment: Thanks. I was concluding the same after a lot of googling before posting it here. Thanks for confirming.